# Using German sharp S (ß) with Bitstream Charter and XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, german

I have a German sharp S (ß) in my document. When I compile the document with XeLaTeX, `ß` is changed to `SS`. It works with the default font but not with Charter (using the XCharter package):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{XCharter}

\begin{document}
Text: ä ö ü ß
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

I have also tried to compile a similar document with pdfLaTeX and the `ß` is displayed correctly in the output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}

\begin{document}
Text: ä ö ü ß
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the correct output from XeLaTeX without replacing every `ß` with `\ss`?

Comment: You can make the ß active and map it to \ss. But I strongly advice not to go this way. xcharter is not suited for xelatex. Find open type versions of the fonts.

Comment: I downloaded the fonts and replaced `\usepackage{XCharter}` with `\setmainfont[Path=fonts/]{Charter Regular}`. Now it's working as expected. Thanks! :) Just out of curiosity: why is XCharter not suited for XeLaTeX? It says in the package description that OTF fonts are provided, so I just assumed that it would work.

Comment: You can use the otf fonts with \setmainfont{Xcharter-Roman.otf} (or something similar), but the package is the support for pdflatex not xelatex.

Comment: also do not use the inputenc and fontenc packages with xelatex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to other font packages, `XCharter.sty` does not distinguish being called by `pdflatex` or XeLaTeX+`fontspec`, so it ends up into defining legacy fonts, using the T1 encoding.

In the T1 encoding, the slot corresponding to ß in Latin-1 (which is respected by UTF-8) has the uppercase form “SS” of the eszet. This is why you get that strange output.

On the other hand, XCharter is available in TeX Live in OpenType format. Depending on your system, you can get away with

```
\setmainfont{XCharter}
```

(if the OpenType fonts in TeX Live are made available to the operating system) or you need to specify the associations explicitly

```
\setmainfont{XCharter}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Roman,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]
```

Don't load `XCharter.sty` along with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

Use `pdflatex` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{xcharter}` **or** `xelatex` with `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{XCharter}`. Both work (the font exists in opentype format):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xcharter}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}

\begin{document}

Text: ä ö ü ß

\end{document}
```

[image]